# Type 'true' has no properties in common with type '{ onlySelf?: boolean; }'

Tags: angular

```
showInvalidFields() {
if (this.subscribeAppForm.controls.subscriptionKey.invalid) {
  this.subscribeAppForm.controls.subscriptionKey.markAsTouched(true);
}
```

}

I looked for many places to find an solution to this error. But no solution can be found. I got this error when migrating my code from Angular 4.0 to Angular 7.2.2. Can any one point out why this error is generated?

Comment: There is probably not enough code - [mcve] to help you

Comment: What is the type signature of `markAsTouched`?

Comment: im sorry, was trying to keep the code as short as possible! the method will be as

`markAsTouched(opts?: {
        onlySelf?: boolean;
    }): void;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
showInvalidFields() {
  if (this.subscribeAppForm.controls.subscriptionKey.invalid) {
    this.subscribeAppForm.controls.subscriptionKey.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
  }
}
```

The type signature has been changed.

Comment: I did bro, but I have less than 15 reputations! Im new, so the site says they are recorded but wont display! sorry!!